# Angular2 Can't resolve all parameters for provideLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I followed the Routing tutorial for Angular2. However, I now get a strange error I can't seem to fix:

127.0.0.1/:21 Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for provideLocationStrategy: (PlatformLocation, ?, Token_ROUTER_CONFIGURATION).

app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {MyComponent} from "./myComponent/myComponent.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MyComponent},
    { path: '**', component: MyComponent}
];
//
//export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
//
//];
//
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {MyComponent} from "./myComponent/myComponent.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        //appRoutingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the docs they export the appRoutingProviders from app.routing.ts, but in the tutorial they don't, so I left it out. Result is the same and it seems to be just an empty array anyways.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: do you have `<base href="/">` on index.html page & `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending all day struggling with this, 5 minutes after posting I found the answer.

I cleared the mapping in my System.config and reinstalled all packages and it worked. Reinstalling the packages without clearing the mapping seems to have installed multiple versions of the same packages, which probably messed things up.

Angular is easy, it's everything around it that makes it hard.